# How to make TRIGGER to my table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have this table:

```
 CREATE TABLE [Alerts]
(
  [Timestamp] datetime,
  [Status] int
)

INSERT INTO [Alerts] ([Timestamp], [Status])
  VALUES
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:00', 1),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:05', 1),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:10', 2),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:15', 2),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:20', 0),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:25', 1),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:30', 1),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:32', 2),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:35', 2),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:40', 0),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:45', 0),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:50', 0)
```

How I can make trigger from this code below:

```
SELECT
  MIN ([main].[Start]) AS [STOP_Begin],
  [main].[End] AS [STOP_End],
  DATEDIFF(s, MIN([main].[Start]), [main].[End]) AS [Interval_Second]
FROM
(
  SELECT
    [starts].[Start],
    MIN([ends].[Timestamp]) AS [End]
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      [Timestamp] AS [Start]
    FROM [Alerts]
    WHERE [Status] = 0
  ) AS [starts] LEFT JOIN [Alerts] AS [ends]
  ON  [starts].[Start] < [ends].[Timestamp]
  AND [ends].[Status] <> 0
  GROUP BY
    [starts].[Start]
) AS [main]
GROUP BY
  [main].[End]
ORDER BY 1
```

So every time I add new input into table [Alerts], 
It change the new table either automatically. 
Should I already made new table or how?

Please see this [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c72cd/25)

Trigger code that do the same like my select code, just say the new table name **newtable**,
 **so i dont need to use my select code every time I add new input**

Comment: please elaborate on your desired final outcome ?

Comment: Please clarify what do you need your trigger to do.

Comment: You want your trigger to do a bunch of SELECTs?

Comment: @SQLGuru , the code I post already right, i want ask how to make it a trigger, so every time i add new input into table **[Alerts]** it change either in my new table

Comment: what do you want changed in the table by the trigger?

Comment: @SQLGuru , please try first my code, what i want is, every time i add new input into table [Alerts] it change either in my new table

Comment: @peterm , please try my code first, and you will understand

Comment: I tried your code and I reached a deadlock. Don't be shy to give more info

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko , deadlock? please see this SQLFiddle [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c72cd/25)

Comment: I say that it is unclear question;)

Comment: What is your "New table"? It sounds like you just want a view rather than a trigger.

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko  **I want trigger that do the same like code that make my new table**

Comment: @GarethD , my new table made by my code. Please see my link. Even i've made new table just name it **newtable** i want trigger that still do the same like my code.

Comment: trigger code that do the same like my select code, just say the new table name **newtable**

Comment: So, you are saying, every time you insert a record in this table, you want a trigger to create a new table, right?

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko, Trigger code that do the same like my select code, just say the new table name **newtable**,
**so i dont need to use my select code every time I add new input**

Comment: You cannot have a trigger that performs a select. It seems like you have an idea that you need a trigger and are not considering other options. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/214ac/1) for how a view would work, before the insert selecting from the view `NewTable` yields different results to after the insert.

Comment: @Raj , no i want trigger that use my condition at select code to trigger just one table. just say my table name **newtable**

Comment: @GarethD , without select, how I can use the same condition in my code to make a trigger , just say the newtable already created

Comment: OK. Let me try this - Newtable already created. You want your trigger to get the result of your select and insert it into you newtable? YES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually answer your question, assuming you have this table in place:

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable 
(   Stop_Begin      DATETIME,
    Stop_End        DATETIME,
    Interval_Second INT
);
```

You can create a trigger that will refresh this table each time a record is added to Alerts:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Alerts_Insert ON Alerts
FOR INSERT
AS
    TRUNCATE TABLE NewTable;

    INSERT NewTable
    SELECT  MIN ([main].[Start]) AS [STOP_Begin],
            [main].[End] AS [STOP_End],
            DATEDIFF(s, MIN([main].[Start]), [main].[End]) AS [Interval_Second]
    FROM    (   SELECT  [starts].[Start],
                        MIN([ends].[Timestamp]) AS [End]
                FROM    (   SELECT  [Timestamp] AS [Start]
                            FROM    [Alerts]
                            WHERE   [Status] = 0
                        ) AS [starts] 
                        LEFT JOIN [Alerts] AS [ends]
                            ON  [starts].[Start] < [ends].[Timestamp]
                            AND [ends].[Status] <> 0
                GROUP BY [starts].[Start]
            ) AS [main]
    GROUP BY [main].[End]
    ORDER BY 1;
```

**[SQL Fiddle for Trigger](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e915c/1)**

**HOWEVER** this is almost certainly bad design, unless you are selecting from `NewTable` **much** more frequently that you are inserting to `Alerts`, and the select query is not instant. In 99% of circumstances a more practical approach would be to just have `NewTable` as a view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.NewTable 
AS
    SELECT  MIN ([main].[Start]) AS [STOP_Begin],
            [main].[End] AS [STOP_End],
            DATEDIFF(s, MIN([main].[Start]), [main].[End]) AS [Interval_Second]
    FROM    (   SELECT  [starts].[Start],
                        MIN([ends].[Timestamp]) AS [End]
                FROM    (   SELECT  [Timestamp] AS [Start]
                            FROM    [Alerts]
                            WHERE   [Status] = 0
                        ) AS [starts] 
                        LEFT JOIN [Alerts] AS [ends]
                            ON  [starts].[Start] < [ends].[Timestamp]
                            AND [ends].[Status] <> 0
                GROUP BY [starts].[Start]
            ) AS [main]
    GROUP BY [main].[End]
    ORDER BY 1;
```

**[SQL Fiddle for View](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/214ac/1)**

Comparing both SQL Fiddles you can see that the SQL on the right remains unchanged and the results are the same. However the view avoids having to maintain `NewTable` so less overhead for inserts to `Alerts` and less places for things to go wrong.